# Save data periodically during execution

Tags: c++

I have a program which executes constantly and I need to save data every minute.

The program process data and every minute I want to save the value of a variable and do some statistical operations to know the variation of this variable.

I thought i can make it with a signal, SIGALRM and alarm(60). My subquestion is, can I put a class method as the destiny method for SIGALRM?

Any other idea to execute a method to save data and do some operations every minute ??

The program is written in C++, runs in Linux an a mono-core processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution using `alarm` will work, both `open` and `write` being asynchronous-signal-safe. Though you have to be aware that interactions between `alarm` and `sleep` are undefined, so don't use them in the same program.

A different solution, especially in case you already use an `epoll`, would be to have a `timerfd` trigger the `epoll`. That will avoid possible undefined interactions.

As for the actual saving, consider forking. This is a technique that I learned from [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) (maybe someone else invented it, but that's where I learned it from), and which I consider totally cool. The point being that the forked process can take all time in the universe to finish writing as much data as you want to disk. It can access the snapshot at the time of forking while the other process keeps running and modifying data. And thanks to page magic done in the kernel, it still all works seamlessly without any risk of corruption, without ever stalling, and without ever needing to look at something like asynchronous IO, which is great.

Comment: Thanks. Forking looks fine. My questions now is how to communicate the instant value of a variable in the processing process to the time-count process. Now i'm remembering all the basics of processes. I think I pipe could be the best way to communicate both process.

Comment: Ah, that is the magic of fork. You _don't need_ to communicate anything. The child knows what the parent knows. The operating system maps all pages belonging to the parent into the child process and tags them copy on write. That means even if the parent modifies some data after forking off, the child still sees the original value. This just rocks for saving snapshots every now and then, no worries whatsoever except the overhead of forking once per minute (but that is totally neglegible). Once the child is done saving, let it die.

Comment: Sorry, but i think i'm little bit confused or I don't understand how to do it. I started with the main program, create a child (fork) to count a minute and when it's done do some operations. Meanwhile the parent is processing and modifying a vector/variable. I thought the child doesn't see the mods the parent do on the variable. And I need to know the changes in the child to do the operations. The problem with forking is all the variables and their values are cloned when you do the fork operation.

Comment: Other way around: Do whatever you do, and once the minute is up, fork. If fork returns a value greater than zero, contine whatever you do (this is the original process). If the return value is zero, you're in the child process. Any data that was there before is still here. Save any data you want, and don't be afraid of blocking or how long it takes (the parent process will run on, and nobody will notice!). When done, exit.

Comment: Many thanks. I will try to do it tonight. Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a class method using something like [boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers)

Apart from that I wouldn't recommend to use signals for that, they are not that reliable, and could, for example, make one of your syscalls to return prematurely.

I would spawn a thread, assuming your monocore doesn't mean no threads, that waits 60 seconds, takes locks, makes calcs, outputs and releases locks.

As they have already suggested, if you have an async compatible system(driven by events) you could use timerfd to generate events.

Answer (score 2):

Saving data from a signal handler is a **very bad idea**. Even if `open` and `write` are async-signal-safe, your data could very well be in an inconsistent state due to a signal interrupting a function that was modifying it.

A much better approach would be to add to all functions which modify the data:

```
if (current_time > last_save_time + 60) save();
```

This will avoid useless saves when the data has not been modified, too. If you don't want the overhead of making a system call to determine the current time on every operation, you could instead install a timer/signal handler that updates `current_time`, as long as you declare it `volatile`.

Another good approach would be to use threads instead of signals. Then you should use a mutex (or better, rwlock) to synchronize access to the data.

Comment: Good idea, but what if the user makes many modifications in 59 seconds and then doesn't save and the program crashes?

Comment: OP's original idea (blindly saving every 60 sec) has the exact same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i think forking is better solution or easier for me. I don't want to use threads. Thanks anyway

Comment: There's nothing mutually exclusive about my solution and forking as part of the save operation. Doing the fork-and-save from a signal handler *will not work*. There's a very real chance you will write corrupt data to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. But if i shouldn't use signals, my new questions is, when i can use a signal and why signals have all theses problems ???

Comment: The short answer to when you can use signals: when the **only** thing you want to do from the signal handler is operate on type `sig_atomic_t` variables. The long answer: on POSIX systems, there is a list of async-signal-safe functions, but even if the library functions you'll use are safe, **your own functions** that operate on your program's data structures are probably not reentrant, in which case you could get data corruption. Attempting **any** nontrivial activity from signal handlers is a programming task which should only be attempted by experts.